# c++: how does memberwise assignment work?

Tags: c++, variable-assignment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How are C array members handled in copy control functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164279/how-are-c-array-members-handled-in-copy-control-functions)

If I don't override the `operator =` of a class, it will use default memberwise assignment.

But what does it mean?

```
struct A {
    int array[100];
};
A a;
A b=a;
```

No error. How does `b` copes `a`'s`array`? Normally `array_b = array_a` is invalid.

Another exampe:

```
struct A {
    vector<int> vec;
};
A a;
A b=a;
```

How does `b` copes `a`'s`vec`? Through assignment(`vec_b = vec_a`), constructor(`vec_b = vector<int>(vec_a)`) or other mystery way?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164279/how-are-c-array-members-handled-in-copy-control-functions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
A b=a;
```

Is not assignment, it is called as **[Copy Initialization](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/036.htm)**.

The implicitly generated copy constructor is called to create an new object `b` from the existing object `a`.
The implicitly generated copy constructor makes a copy of the `array` member.

For completeness I am going to add here the standard citation from the marked duplicate.

**C++03 Standard: 12.8 (Copying class objects)**

> Each subobject is copied in the manner appropriate to its type:
>
> - if the subobject is of class type, the copy constructor for the class is used;
> - **if the subobject is an array, each element is copied, in the manner appropriate to the element type;**
> - if the subobject is of scalar type, the built-in assignment operator is used.

Comment: Generally, yes. What is a shallow copy of an array though?

Comment: @KonradRudolph: In this case an `memcpy`.The *shallow copy* would apply to pointers and that is the reason for **Rule of Three**.

Comment: @Als Word. And this also can be applied to the OP's "Normally array_b = array_a is invalid." where you can't use an assignment like that, but you can construct new arrays that way (as long as the rhs is an array literal).

Comment: @ChrisA. It is if the array elements are pointers.

Comment: @Als Do you mean that its a shallow copy here and modifying array variable for object a will modify the content for array variable for object b ?

Comment: @Als I am individually able to modify array variable for object a and b without 11 affecting the content of the other

Comment: @Ritesh on which type of objects a and b?

Comment: @MrLister yeah ... i did something like this to make a check:-

Comment: for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
 cout << a.array[i];
}
cout <<endl;
a.array[1]=23;
A b=a;
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
 cout << b.array[i];
}
b.array[1]=44;
cout<<endl;
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
 cout << a.array[i];
}

Comment: The contents of the object get memcpy'd. Like Mr Fooz says, that includes non-pointer arrays.

Comment: @FredOverflow here its the subobject is an array, each element is assigned, in the manner appropriate to the element type; does that mean its equivalent to deep copy ? – Ritesh just

Comment: @Ritesh: Each element is *copied* not *assigned* there is no assignment here, this is copy construction.

Comment: @Als I know that. Your answer didn’t say it though, even though the question was explicitly after array members.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Hmm, It was a hint I couldn't follow, I guess that's my bad :)

Answer (score 1):

If the members have copy constructors, they get invoked.  If not, the default copy constructor does the equivalent of memcpy.  See [Memberwise Assignment and Initialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0c54csc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

In the case of non-pointer arrays, each element is copied.