# Regarding C++ OOP array member copying behavior

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, member

I know this may sound trivial, but I'm new to C++ OOP. Thanks a lot for help!

For example, for the following code:

```
using namespace std;

class Object {
public:
    int arr[10];
    Object(int b) {memset(arr, 0, sizeof(arr));}
};

void test(Object &first, Object other)
{
    cout << "Test" << endl;
    cout << (first.arr) << endl;
    cout << (other.arr) << endl;
    return;
}

int main() 
{
    Object x(2);
    Object y(3);
    test(x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that in the function declaration `void test(Object &first, Object other)`, the first parameter takes the original alias, while the second takes a copy.

I'm aware that `Object other` creates a local copy of the object passed into this function. But question is: is the member `arr` copied as well? In other words, when calling `test(x, y)` does `y.arr` and `other.arr` point to the same or different array?

If a copy is performed, does it perform shallow or deep copy?

What then is the case when instead of declaring `int arr[10]`, a `int *arr` is used and the `arr` is dynamically allocated in the constructor, using the `new` keyword?

Thanks a lot!

**Edit: My findings**

Is it that in the case of declaring `int arr[10]`, a new array is copied, and the elements inside the new array point to the objects in the original array?

When instead `new` keyword is used to dynamically allocate, the copied array is still a pointer to the array of the copied object?

Comment: You went to the trouble of writing most of the code needed to find the answer for yourself; wouldn't it be more satisfying to finish the job?

Comment: To be honest, I'm seeking a confirmation to my findings: Is it that while a new array is copied, the elements inside the array point to the objects in the original array? When instead `new` is used to dynamically allocate, the array is still a pointer to the array of the copied object?

Comment: Post does not appear to have been edited; what were your findings?

Comment: Please see the comment above, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164279/how-are-c-array-members-handled-in-copy-control-functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default copy constructor does member wise copy (thanks to Yuri whose comment below clarified this, as I had originally said bitwise copy). You can see this more clearly by changing your constructor and by providing an output operator for Object:

```
#include <algorithm> // for fill()
using namespace std;

class Object {
  private:
    int arr[10];
  public:
    Object(int i=0);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& ostr, const Object& obj);
};

Object::Object(int i)
{
  fill(arr, arr + 10, i); 
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& ostr, const Object& obj)
{
   ostr << "outputting member 'int arr[10]' of size " << sizeof(obj.arr)/sizeof(int) << "\n";

   for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(obj.arr)/sizeof(int); i++)  {

        ostr << obj.arr[i] << ", ";

   } 
   ostr << "\n";
   return ostr;
}

void test(Object &first, Object other)
{
    cout << "Test" << endl;
    cout << first << endl;
    cout << other << endl;
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
 Object x(4);
 Object y(x);

 test(x, y);
 return 0;
}
```

"What then is the case when instead of declaring int arr[10], a int *arr is used and the arr is dynamically allocated in the constructor, using the new keyword?"

In that case both objects will point to the same address, which means y could change the dynamically allocated array of x, and vice versa. Probably not what you want. So you would need to supply a copy constructor to avoid this:

```
#include <algorithm> // for fill()
using namespace std;

class Object {
  private:
    int *p;
  public:
    Object(int i=0);
    Object(const Object& rhs);
    ~Object();
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& ostr, const Object& obj);
};

Object::Object(int i)
{
  p = new int[10];  
  fill(p, p + 10, i); 
}
Object::Object(const Object& rhs)
{
   p = new int[10];
   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        p[i] = rhs.p[i];
    }    
}

Object::~Object()
{
      delete [] p;
}  

ostream& operator<<(ostream& ostr, const Object& obj)
{                 
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)  {
            ostr << obj.p[i] << ", ";
   } 
   ostr << "\n";
   return ostr;
}

void test(Object &first, Object other)
{
    cout << "Test" << endl;
    cout << first << endl;
    cout << other << endl;
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{

    Object x(4);
    cout << x << endl;
    Object y(5);
    test(x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"The default copy constructor does bitwise copy."_ No, it does memberwise copy.

Comment: I agree, other than the slight mistake, this has been helpful. Thanks!